# List of character vector combinations

Tags: r, combinations

I'm trying to take a vector with names of four possible models "x1","x2","x3","x4" and create a longer vector of all possible permutations of these terms, so I can then start a dataframe with properties of each.

The code below, looks like it should work but doesn't. The elements don't get pasted together, for example "x1" and "x2" combination should result in a "x1x2" model name but instead it remains "x1" "x2".

```
models <- c("x1","x2","x3","x4")

modelist<- as.character()
for(i in 1:4){
  modelist <- c(modelist,combn(models,m=i,FUN=paste0,simplify = T))
}
modelist
```

Since I'm not looking for interaction terms, x1x1 should not appear, but I'd be interested to know how to do it either way for future reference.

Here's the output I'm looking for:

```
modelist <- c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x1x2","x1x3","x1x4","x2x3","x2x4","x3x4",
            "x1x2x3","x2x3x4","x1x2x4","x1x3x4","x1x2x3x4")
```

That's what should be contained in modelist.

Comment: Try it with with `collapse = ""` as in `combn(models, m=i, FUN=paste, collapse = "", simplify = T)`

Comment: Do you want anything removed?  E.g. should `x1x1` appear?

Comment: Richard. paste0() didn't work, paste() didn't work. However your suggestion for paste() and collapse="" seems to have worked. So strange?

Comment: They're actually combinations not permutations, since order is irrelevant: you don't count "x3x2" as different to "x2x3".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`paste()` with its default arguments, and also with `sep = ""`, will not work because the result from `combn()` is an atomic vector as well, but for each combination.  So it's basically the same as the following for every combination.

```
paste(letters[1:4])
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
paste(letters[1:4], sep = "")
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
paste(letters[1:4], collapse = "")
# [1] "abcd"
```

So you will want to use `collapse = ""` in `paste()`.  Here's an `lapply()` solution.

```
unlist(lapply(1:4, function(i) combn(models, i, paste, collapse = "")))
#  [1] "x1"       "x2"       "x3"       "x4"       "x1x2"     "x1x3"     "x1x4"
#  [8] "x2x3"     "x2x4"     "x3x4"     "x1x2x3"   "x1x2x4"   "x1x3x4"   "x2x3x4"
# [15] "x1x2x3x4"
```

If you want to continue using a `for()` loop, I would recommend you allocate a list instead of building the character vector in the loop.  It's much more efficient.  You could allocate a character vector of length `sum(choose(4, 1:4))`, but the loop indexing is a bit tricky and unlisting the list is a lot easier than worrying about all that. Furthermore, lists are the standard structure to use when dealing with similar objects of different lengths.

```
modlist <- vector("list", 4)
for(i in 1:4) {
    modlist[[i]] <- combn(models, i, paste, collapse = "")
}
unlist(modlist)
#  [1] "x1"       "x2"       "x3"       "x4"       "x1x2"     "x1x3"     "x1x4"
#  [8] "x2x3"     "x2x4"     "x3x4"     "x1x2x3"   "x1x2x4"   "x1x3x4"   "x2x3x4"
# [15] "x1x2x3x4"
```